# Cannot do incremental training with DNNRegressor

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I try to write a learning case according to google's course which uses DNNRegressor to setup a neural nets(intro_to_neural_nets). But I get an error when executing the script:

```
...
File "/~/.tf-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 662, in iterations
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot set `iterations` to a new Variable after "
RuntimeError: Cannot set `iterations` to a new Variable after the Optimizer weights have been created
```

In my code I follow the sample to separate steps to multiple periods to execute and the codes is below:

```
def training(learning_rate, steps, batch_size, hidden_units, samples, targets, test_samples, test_targets, periods = 10):
  steps_per_period = steps / periods

  #create DNNRegressor Object
  my_optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=0.9, clipnorm=5.0)
  dnn_regressor = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
    feature_columns = construct_feature_columns(samples),
    hidden_units = hidden_units,
    optimizer = my_optimizer
  )

  # Create input functions.
  training_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(samples, 
                                          targets, 
                                          batch_size=batch_size)
  predict_training_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(samples, 
                                                  targets, 
                                                  num_epochs=1, 
                                                  shuffle=False)
  predict_validation_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(test_samples, 
                                                    test_targets, 
                                                    num_epochs=1, 
                                                    shuffle=False)
  # Train the model, but do so inside a loop so that we can periodically assess
  # loss metrics.
  print("Training model...")
  print("RMSE (on training data):")
  training_rmse = []
  validation_rmse = []
  for period in range (0, periods):
    # Train the model, starting from the prior state.
    print("Period[%s]" % (period+1))
    dnn_regressor.train(
        input_fn=training_input_fn,
        steps=steps_per_period
    )
...
```

The first period executed successfully but it failed with upper error on the second iteration and jumped out.

I add an immediate train action again to test whether these is any other steps causing this problem, but it showed me that the problem is here(invoke training with steps again)

```
#changed code
    print("Period[%s]" % (period+1))
    dnn_regressor.train(
        input_fn=training_input_fn,
        steps=steps_per_period
    )
    print("--- again")
    dnn_regressor.train(
        input_fn=training_input_fn
    )
```

with output

```
Training model...
RMSE (on training data):
Period[1]
WARNING:tensorflow:From /~/.tf-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1630: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /~/.tf-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/training_util.py:236: Variable.initialized_value (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use Variable.read_value. Variables in 2.X are initialized automatically both in eager and graph (inside tf.defun) contexts.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /~/.tf-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/head/base_head.py:550: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /~/.tf-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/clip_ops.py:172: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
WARNING:tensorflow:From /~/.tf-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/model_fn.py:337: scalar (from tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.TensorShape([]).
2019-09-26 10:27:41.728179: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-09-26 10:27:41.742511: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fe4f6546af0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-09-26 10:27:41.742564: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
--- again
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/~/Documents/workspace/tensorflow/intro_to_neural_nets.py", line 174, in <module>
    test_targets=test_Y)
  File "/~/Documents/workspace/tensorflow/intro_to_neural_nets.py", line 123, in training
    input_fn=training_input_fn
  File "/~/.tf-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 367, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/~/.tf-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1158, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/~/.tf-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1188, in _train_model_default
    features, labels, ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/~/.tf-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1146, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/~/.tf-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 1166, in _model_fn
    batch_norm=batch_norm)
  File "/~/.tf-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 580, in dnn_model_fn_v2
    optimizer.iterations = training_util.get_or_create_global_step()
  File "/~/.tf-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 561, in __setattr__
    super(OptimizerV2, self).__setattr__(name, value)
  File "/~/.tf-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 662, in iterations
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot set `iterations` to a new Variable after "
RuntimeError: Cannot set `iterations` to a new Variable after the Optimizer weights have been created
```

I don't know why this error happens and how to fix it. Thanks for anybody's help. By the way if anyone can tell me how to avoid/eliminate those warnings, it is also highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong here. I edited the example in the TensorFlow documentation using canned estimators and was unable to use any tf.keras.optimizer() to do training with multiple estimator.train(...) calls. Your code will likely run without specifying an optimizer, but I'm not sure what learning rate or optimizer is used in that case...

I just opened this as an issue on the TF github. See here for updates:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33358

If you want to get going immediately, you could downgrade your code to TF 1.x so that you can roughly match the version of the google machine learning crash course.

If you're feeling more ambitious, the TF team recommends starting to learn TensorFlow with Keras. From the documentation page about premade Estimators:

> Note that in TensorFlow 2.0, the [Keras API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras) can accomplish many of these same tasks, and is believed to be an easier API to learn. If you are starting fresh, we would recommend you start with Keras. For more information about the available high level APIs in TensorFlow 2.0, see [Standardizing on Keras](https://medium.com/tensorflow/standardizing-on-keras-guidance-on-high-level-apis-in-tensorflow-2-0-bad2b04c819a).

Edit: An option to monitor training that would be low effort would be to use [tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started). The changes to your code would be to:

1. Remove the looping.
2. Add model_dir parameter to find logs.

```py
dnn_regressor = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
    feature_columns = construct_feature_columns(samples),
    hidden_units = hidden_units,
    optimizer = my_optimizer,
    model_dir = /tmp/log_dir
  )
```

3. Open TensorBoard with (the reload_multifile option might not be necessary):

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir '/tmp/log_dir' --reload_multifile=true
```

TensorBoard is defaulted to update every 30 seconds, but you could update faster if you wanted to monitor training more closely. This tool is also very cool if you want to explore what the model looks like in more detail!

EDIT 2: There is a simple workaround suggested to me on github. This works by creating a callable rather than an instance of `optimizer` to pass to the `Estimator`. Using the callable, a new instance is created whenever `Estimator.train()` is called, so the issue of trying to set `iterations` on an existing `Optimizer` is avoided.

```
from functools import partial

my_optimizer = partial(SGD, learning_rate=leraning_rate, momentum=0.9, clipnorm=5.0)
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please consider adding more of your questions here in case the external link becomes invalid.

Comment: The same error occurs with `tf.estimator.LinearRegressor` and `tf.keras.optimizers.SGD` as in https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xRuxIVhyo0tDSMuaN22UDtmzJYs9GvOr

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
from functools import partial

my_optimizer = partial(SGD, learning_rate=leraning_rate, momentum=0.9, clipnorm=5.0)
```

it worked for me this way:

```
from functools import partial

my_optimizer = partial(optimizers.SGD, learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=0.9, clipnorm=5.0)
```